# Changing variable with Tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently working on a project for fun in which I have a login screen followed by a main menu. This is my first main project because I am very new to Python and still learning.

What I would like to do is, after the user logs in correctly, they are faced with the main menu (Toplevel window behind the root window). In this menu I would like the user to be able to choose a difficulty (easy, medium, hard)

This is the error I am getting: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'radius' referenced before assignment

Here is my code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import random, randint
from time import time
import os
import sys
import tkinter.messagebox as tm
import hashlib, uuid
import re
import turtle

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

from tkinter import *

user_get = 0
variable = 1
diffSetting = 9



class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)#Set __init__ to the master class
        self.grid()
        self.create_main()#Creates function
        self.Read()
        changeVariable1(self)
        changeVariable2(self)
        changeVariable3(self)

def Read(self):
    top = Tk()
    top.geometry("%dx%d%+d%+d" % (420, 500, 250, 125))

    top.title = Label(top, text="Menu ", font='Helvetica 10 bold')#TITLE 
    top.title.grid(row=0, column=2)

    top.title = Label(top, text="    ", font='Helvetica 10 bold')#blank line
    top.title.grid(row=1, column=1)

    top.user_entry_label = Label(top, text="Difficulty: ", font='Helvetica 10 bold')#USERNAME LABEL
    top.user_entry_label.grid(row=3, column=1)

    top.easybutt = Button(top, text="Easy",  font='Helvetica 10 bold', command = changeVariable1(self))#easy
    top.easybutt.grid(row=3, column=2)

    top.medbutt = Button(top, text="Medium",  font='Helvetica 10 bold', command = changeVariable2(self))#med
    top.medbutt.grid(row=3, column=3)

    top.hrdbutt = Button(top, text="Hard",  font='Helvetica 10 bold', command = changeVariable3(self))#hrd
    top.hrdbutt.grid(row=3, column=4)

    top.title = Label(top, text="    ", font='Helvetica 10 bold')#blank line
    top.title.grid(row=4, column=1)




    def create_main(self):
        self.title = Label(self, text="Reflex Login ", font='Helvetica 10 bold')#TITLE 
        self.title.grid(row=0, column=2)

        self.user_entry_label = Label(self, text="Username: ", font='Helvetica 10 bold')#USERNAME LABEL
        self.user_entry_label.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.user_entry = Entry(self)                        #USERNAME ENTRY BOX
        self.user_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)

        self.pass_entry_label = Label(self, text="Password: ", font='Helvetica 10 bold')#PASSWORD LABEL
        self.pass_entry_label.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.pass_entry = Entry(self, show="●")                        #PASSWORD ENTRY BOX
        self.pass_entry.grid(row=2, column=2)

        self.sign_in_butt = Button(self, text="Sign In",  font='Helvetica 10 bold', command = self.logging_in)#SIGN IN BUTTON
        self.sign_in_butt.grid(row=3, column=2)

        self.register_butt = Button(self, text="Register",font='Helvetica 10 bold', command = self.register)#Register button
        self.register_butt.grid(row=4, column=2)

        self.title = Label(self, text="    ", font='Helvetica 10 bold')#blank line 
        self.title.grid(row=5, column=2)

        self.title = Label(self, text="    ", font='Helvetica 10 bold')#blank line
        self.title.grid(row=6, column=2)

    #username criteria
        self.title = Label(self, text="---------------------------------------", font='Helvetica 10 bold')#seperator 
        self.title.grid(row=6, column=2)
        self.title = Label(self, text="Username Criteria: ", font='Helvetica 10 bold')#TITLE 
        self.title.grid(row=7, column=2)
        self.title = Label(self, text="One number 1-9.", font='Helvetica 10') 
        self.title.grid(row=8, column=2)
        self.title = Label(self, text="6-12 characters in length.", font='Helvetica 10') 
        self.title.grid(row=9, column=2)
        self.title = Label(self, text="Include no spaces.", font='Helvetica 10')
        self.title.grid(row=10, column=2)

    #password criteria
        self.title = Label(self, text="    ", font='Helvetica 10 bold')#blank line
        self.title.grid(row=11, column=2)
        self.title = Label(self, text="---------------------------------------", font='Helvetica 10 bold')#seperator
        self.title.grid(row=11, column=2)
        self.title = Label(self, text="Password Criteria: ", font='Helvetica 10 bold')#TITLE 
        self.title.grid(row=12, column=2)
        self.title = Label(self, text="One number 1-9.", font='Helvetica 10') 
        self.title.grid(row=13, column=2)
        self.title = Label(self, text="6-12 characters in length.", font='Helvetica 10') 
        self.title.grid(row=14, column=2)
        self.title = Label(self, text="One uppercase letter and one lowercase letter.", font='Helvetica 10') 
        self.title.grid(row=15, column=2)
        self.title = Label(self, text="One special character [~!@#$%^&*].", font='Helvetica 10')
        self.title.grid(row=16, column=2)
        self.title = Label(self, text="Include no spaces.", font='Helvetica 10')
        self.title.grid(row=17, column=2)
        self.title = Label(self, text="---------------------------------------", font='Helvetica 10 bold')#seperator
        self.title.grid(row=18, column=2)


    def logging_in(self):
        global user_get
        user_get = self.user_entry.get()#Retrieve Username
        global pass_get
        pass_get = self.pass_entry.get()#Retrieve Password
        hash_object = hashlib.md5(pass_get.encode())
        for line in open("details.txt","r").readlines(): #Read the lines
            login_info = line.split() #Split on the space, and store the results in a list of two strings
            if user_get == login_info[0] and (hash_object.hexdigest()) == login_info[1]:
                tm.showinfo("Success", 'Login Correct!')
                root.destroy()
                return True
        tm.showerror('Error', 'Login Incorrect')
        return False


    def register(self):
        global user_get
        user_get = self.user_entry.get()
        pass_get = self.pass_entry.get()
        user_get = self.user_entry.get()#Retrieve Username
        pass_get = self.pass_entry.get()#Retrieve Password
        hash_object = hashlib.md5(pass_get.encode())

    #validation check#
    #passvalidation
        is_valid = False 
        if (len(pass_get)<6 or len(pass_get)>12):
            tm.showerror("Invalid!", 'Password should be between 6 and 12. Try again')
            is_valid = False
        elif not re.search("[A-Z]",pass_get):
            tm.showerror("Invalid!", 'Password should contain one letter between [A-Z]. Try again')
            is_valid = False
        elif not re.search("[a-z]",pass_get):
            tm.showerror("Invalid!", 'Password should contain one letter between [a-z]. Try again')
            is_valid = False
        elif not re.search("[1-9]",pass_get):
            tm.showerror("Invalid!", 'Password should contain one number between [1-9]. Try again')
            is_valid = False
        elif not re.search("[~!@#$%^&*]",pass_get):
            tm.showerror("Invalid!", 'Password should contain at least one letter in [~!@#$%^&*]. Try again')
            is_valid = False
        elif re.search("[\s]",pass_get):
            tm.showerror("Invalid!", 'Password should not contain any space. Try again')
            is_valid = False
        else:
            is_valid = True

    #uservalidation
        user_valid = False 
        if (len(user_get)<6 or len(user_get)>12):
            tm.showerror("Invalid!", 'Username should be between 6 and 12. Try again')
            user_valid = False
        elif not re.search("[1-9]",user_get):
            tm.showerror("Invalid!", 'Username should contain one number between [1-9]. Try again')
            user_valid = False
        elif re.search("[\s]",user_get):
            tm.showerror("Invalid!", 'Username should not contain any space. Try again')
            user_valid = False
    else:
            user_valid = True

        if(is_valid) and (user_valid): 
            tm.showinfo("Valid!", 'Username and Password is valid')    
            file = open('details.txt', 'a+')
            file.write(user_get)
            file.write(" ")
            file.write(hash_object.hexdigest())
            file.write("\n")
            file.close()

def changeVariable1(self):
    global difficulty
    self.difficulty = 12

def changeVariable2(self):
    global difficulty
    self.difficulty = 16

def changeVariable3(self):
    global difficulty
    self.difficulty = 20



######watch video



root = Tk()
root.title("Reflex Aim Training")
root.geometry("%dx%d%+d%+d" % (420, 500, 250, 125))
app = Application(root)#The frame is inside the widgit
#root.overrideredirect(True)                                                                                                                                        ###############################
root.mainloop()#Keeps the window open/running
top = Toplevel()
top.title("Main Menu")



#reset
reset = int(input("Would you like to continue or start fresh? 1 for fresh start, Any other number for continue: "))

if reset == 1:
    os.remove('stats.txt')
    os.remove('maths.txt')    
    print("Your previous scores have been deleted")
else:
    print("We will keep your previous scores stored.")


#while True:
#    diffSetting=int(input("Set the difficulty(1-3): "))
#    
#    if diffSetting == 1:
#        difficulty = 12
#        break
##    elif diffSetting == 2:
 #       difficulty = 16
  #      break
   # elif diffSetting == 3:
    #    difficulty = 20
     #   break
   # else:
        #print("Please choose a difficulty setting between 1 to 3.")

def addscore():
    global score
    score += 2

def deletescore():
    global score
    score -= 1

def my_circle(color):

    if diffSetting==1:
        radius = (30)
    elif diffSetting==2:
        radius = (20)
    elif diffSetting==3:
        radius = (10)


    circle = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
    circle.shapesize(radius / CURSOR_SIZE)
    circle.color('black', color) 

    circle.penup()

    while True:
        nx = randint(2 * radius - width // 2, width // 2 - radius * 2)
        ny = randint(2 * radius - height // 2, height // 2 - radius * 2)

        circle.goto(nx, ny)

        for other_radius, other_circle in circles:
            if circle.distance(other_circle) < 2 * max(radius,         other_radius):
                break
            else:
                break

    circle.onclick(lambda x,y,t=circle: (circle.hideturtle(), addscore()))
    circle.showturtle()



    return radius, circle

def play():
    rgb = (random(), random(), random())

    timeTaken = time() - startTime

    circles.append(my_circle(rgb))

    screen.title('SCORE: {}, TIME LEFT: {}'.format(score, int(round(gameLength - timeTaken, 0))))

    if time() - startTime > gameLength:
        screen.title('FINAL SCORE: {}'.format(score))
        screen.onclick(None)
        screen.clear()
    else:
        screen.ontimer(play, 1000 // difficulty)



screen = Screen()
screen.title("Reflex Aim Training")
screen.bgcolor("grey")

width, height = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()

score = 0

circles = []

gameLength = 30

screen.onclick(lambda x, y: deletescore())

startTime = time()

play()

screen.mainloop()



print ("{} points, Well Done!".format(score))

#storingscore
file = open('scoreboard.txt', 'r')
name = file.readline()
high_score = int(file.readline())
file.close()

plus_score = (score)-(high_score)
minus_score = (high_score)-(score)


if score > high_score:
    file = open('scoreboard.txt', 'w')
    file.write(str(user_get) + '\n' + str(score) + '\n' "You beat the         previous high score by: "+str(plus_score)+" points!")
    file.close()

if high_score > score:
    file = open('scoreboard.txt', 'w')
    file.write(str(user_get) + '\n' + str(score) + '\n' "You missed the high     score by: "+str(minus_score)+" points!")
    file.close()

if score == high_score:
    file = open('scoreboard.txt', 'w')
    file.write(str(user_get) + '\n' + str(score) + '\n' "You drew with the high score!")
    file.close()

file = open('stats.txt', 'a+')
file.write('\n' + 'Score: ' +str(score))
file.close()

numbers = []
with open('stats.txt') as fh:
    count = 0
    for line in fh:
        count += 1
        numbers.append(float(line.split()[1]))

file = open('maths.txt', 'w+')
file.write('Average Score: ' + str(sum(numbers)/len(numbers)) + "\n")
file.write('Maximum Score: ' + str(max(numbers)) + "\n")
file.write('Minimum Score: ' + str(min(numbers)) + "\n")
maxn = max(numbers)
minn = min(numbers)
rangex = (maxn) - (minn)
file.write('Range of Scores: ' + str(rangex) + "\n")

l = []

with open('stats.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i in f:
        l.append(int(i.split(':')[1].strip()))

import statistics
stdevi = statistics.stdev(l)
file.write('Standard Deviation: ' + str(stdevi) + "\n")

file.close()
```

*Not sure how much of my code is needed*

What my GUI looks like: https://gyazo.com/db67e84b7d7b1dbff5408d8151c168be

I am facing multiple errors when trying to use other people's answers of this topic which is why I thought to re-ask the question. Thanks for the help

Comment: Just add `radius=30` at the start of your function `my_circle(color)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn't so much that you're getting errors, the issue is why you thought this mess would run at all.  The first half is badly broken but at least matches your description of the code.  The second half, starting around `######watch video`, is a circus of circling turtles, videos, random numbers, high score lists, statistics, etc.  It looks like you collected anything that looked interesting, stuck it all in the same file and hoped something positive would happen.

Tossing the nonsense, here's my rework of the part of your code that tries to achieve the objective you outlined:

```
import re
import hashlib
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tm

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.difficulty = -1

        self.grid()
        self.login = self.create_main()
        self.read = None

        self.changeVariable1()

    def changeVariable1(self):
        self.difficulty = 12

    def changeVariable2(self):
        self.difficulty = 16

    def changeVariable3(self):
        self.difficulty = 20

    def create_read(self):
        read = Toplevel()
        read.geometry("%dx%d%+d%+d" % (420, 500, 250, 125))

        Label(read, text="Menu ", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=0, column=2)
        Label(read, text="    ", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=1, column=1)
        Label(read, text="Difficulty: ", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=3, column=1)

        Button(read, text="Easy", font='Helvetica 10 bold', command=self.changeVariable1()).grid(row=3, column=2)
        Button(read, text="Medium", font='Helvetica 10 bold', command=self.changeVariable2()).grid(row=3, column=3)
        Button(read, text="Hard", font='Helvetica 10 bold', command=self.changeVariable3()).grid(row=3, column=4)

        Label(read, text="    ", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=4, column=1)

        return read

    def create_main(self):
        login = Toplevel()

        Label(login, text="Reflex Login ", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=0, column=2)
        Label(login, text="Username: ", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.user_entry = Entry(login)  # USERNAME ENTRY BOX
        self.user_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)

        Label(login, text="Password: ", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.pass_entry = Entry(login, show="●")  # PASSWORD ENTRY BOX
        self.pass_entry.grid(row=2, column=2)

        Button(login, text="Sign In", font='Helvetica 10 bold', command=self.logging_in).grid(row=3, column=2)
        Button(login, text="Register", font='Helvetica 10 bold', command=self.register).grid(row=4, column=2)

        Label(login, text="    ", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=5, column=2)
        Label(login, text="    ", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=6, column=2)

        # username criteria
        Label(login, text="---------------------------------------", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=6, column=2)
        Label(login, text="Username Criteria: ", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=7, column=2)
        Label(login, text="One number 1-9.", font='Helvetica 10').grid(row=8, column=2)
        Label(login, text="6-12 characters in length.", font='Helvetica 10').grid(row=9, column=2)
        Label(login, text="Include no spaces.", font='Helvetica 10').grid(row=10, column=2)

        # password criteria
        Label(login, text="    ", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=11, column=2)
        Label(login, text="---------------------------------------", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=11, column=2)
        Label(login, text="Password Criteria: ", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=12, column=2)
        Label(login, text="One number 1-9.", font='Helvetica 10').grid(row=13, column=2)
        Label(login, text="6-12 characters in length.", font='Helvetica 10').grid(row=14, column=2)
        Label(login, text="One uppercase letter and one lowercase letter.", font='Helvetica 10').grid(row=15, column=2)
        Label(login, text="One special character [~!@#$%^&*].", font='Helvetica 10').grid(row=16, column=2)
        Label(login, text="Include no spaces.", font='Helvetica 10').grid(row=17, column=2)
        Label(login, text="---------------------------------------", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=18, column=2)

        return login

    def logging_in(self):
        user_get = self.user_entry.get()  # Retrieve Username
        pass_get = self.pass_entry.get()  # Retrieve Password
        hash_object = hashlib.md5(pass_get.encode())

        for line in open("details.txt", "r").readlines():
            login_info = line.split()  # Split on the space, and store the results in a list of two strings

            if user_get == login_info[0] and hash_object.hexdigest() == login_info[1]:
                tm.showinfo("Success", 'Login Correct!')
                self.login.destroy()
                self.read = self.create_read()
                return True

        tm.showerror('Error', 'Login Incorrect')
        return False

    def register(self):
        user_get = self.user_entry.get()  # Retrieve Username
        pass_get = self.pass_entry.get()  # Retrieve Password
        hash_object = hashlib.md5(pass_get.encode())

        # validation check
        # pass validation
        is_valid = False

        if len(pass_get) < 6 or len(pass_get) > 12:
            tm.showerror("Invalid!", 'Password should be between 6 and 12. Try again')
        elif not re.search(r"[A-Z]", pass_get):
            tm.showerror("Invalid!", 'Password should contain one letter between [A-Z]. Try again')
        elif not re.search(r"[a-z]", pass_get):
            tm.showerror("Invalid!", 'Password should contain one letter between [a-z]. Try again')
        elif not re.search(r"[1-9]", pass_get):
            tm.showerror("Invalid!", 'Password should contain one number between [1-9]. Try again')
        elif not re.search(r"[~!@#$%^&*]", pass_get):
            tm.showerror("Invalid!", 'Password should contain at least one letter in [~!@#$%^&*]. Try again')
        elif re.search(r"\s", pass_get):
            tm.showerror("Invalid!", 'Password should not contain any space. Try again')
        else:
            is_valid = True

        # user validation
        user_valid = False

        if len(user_get) < 6 or len(user_get) > 12:
            tm.showerror("Invalid!", 'Username should be between 6 and 12. Try again')
        elif not re.search(r"[1-9]", user_get):
            tm.showerror("Invalid!", 'Username should contain one number between [1-9]. Try again')
        elif re.search(r"\s", user_get):
            tm.showerror("Invalid!", 'Username should not contain any space. Try again')
        else:
            user_valid = True

        if is_valid and user_valid:
            tm.showinfo("Valid!", 'Username and Password is valid')
            file = open('details.txt', 'a+')
            file.write(user_get)
            file.write(" ")
            file.write(hash_object.hexdigest())
            file.write("\n")
            file.close()

root = Tk()

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

It opens an initial window that let's you register and login.  If you login successfully, it closes that window and opens another with the three difficulty buttons.  Add a small chunk of code, test it, once it works, move on to the next chunk.

Comment: When I try to run this with your amended code I get this error:   File "I:\My Drive\testvalidate.py", line 214, in my_circle
    if difficulty == 12:
NameError: name 'difficulty' is not defined